# Where does SPFolder store it's "Created By" information?

Tags: 2010, column, folder, user

Here's an odd one:

I have a content type derived from SPFolder, that I am creating through code.  As part of the creation process, I am trying to set the "Created By" information to be the user who should be attributed as the creator of the folder.  I'm using the following code:

```
// after setting some other field values:

SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.LoginName);
folderItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author] = userValue;
folderItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created_x0020_By] = userValue;
folderItem.SystemUpdate(false);
```

Now, if I go in with Powershell or SharePoint Manager, I can see that in the folder's properties and in the folder's item's properties, the value of `vti_author` and `display_urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Author` is the correct user value, and the only place I can find `SHAREPOINT\system` is in `vti_modifiedby`.

However, when I go and view properties of the folder (through the SharePoint UI), in the view form, the System Account is listed for both created by and modified by.  And, if I add "Created By" to the list view, it's all System Account there too.

So where is SharePoint pulling that from?  What other mystery field do I need to set to get my user as the Created By person?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Author field to just an SPUser object. I have done this before and that worked.

Comment: @spevilgenius, thanks for the suggestion, but that did not work.  Using an SPUser object still ends up showing created by System Account in both view form and list view.

Comment: Impersonate as that user and create folder under his account. That should do the trick. Code sample:http://www.sharepointdeveloperhq.com/2009/04/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the system properties (author, editor, ...) you'll have to use `SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()`

```
SPListItem item = ...; 
item["Created By"] = web.EnsureUser("luisb").ID; 
item["Modified By"] = item["Modified By"]; 
item["Created"] = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3); 
item["Modified"] = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000"); 
item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

See this post:
http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2009/04/13/sharepoint-2007-update-system-properties-created-created-by-modified-modified-by.aspx

---

Update Sept. 30, 2021 (by the OP)

Seven years later and I'm running into this problem again, so I found myself back here.

I think this answer would benefit by adding a couple subtleties I discovered this time around.  Something that is mentioned in the article linked to that was not captured here is this:

> I did notice a bug that the "Created By” (aka Author) field wouldn’t
> update unless also the “Modified By” (aka Editor) field was set
> (either to a new or it’s current value).

I found this to be true, however, I was able to successfully update the `Author` field (as long as I *also* updated the `Editor` field) even using `SPListItem.SystemUpdate()`.

The place where `SystemUpdate()` did *not* work, and where I had to use `UpdateOverWriteVersion()` was when trying to update the `Created` date field.

So there are two quirks to keep in mind here, but they seem to be independent of each other.

(I did not try modifying the `Modified` date field, so I can't say for sure if you have to use `UpdateOverwriteVersion()` to do that.)